# Emacs org-journal todo items don't show up in org-agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-journal

I am wondering how you can make todo items from the journal show up in the agenda view.

Currently, my org set up is as follows

```
(setq org-directory "~/org/")
(setq org-agenda-files (directory-files-recursively "~/org/" "\\.org$"))
(setq org-log-done 'time)
(setq org-journal-dir "~/org/11 Journal/")
(setq org-journal-file-format "%Y-%m-%d.org")
```

However, appending TODO items to my journal, it does not seem to show up later on in my todo list. Any clue how to make them show up?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different way to set `org-agenda-files`. The form you show above calculates the list at initialization, so any newly created journal files are not part of the list: you would have to add them manually.

In general, Org mode calls the *function* `org-agenda-files` when it needs to calculate the list of agenda files. In the case above, if you evaluate `(org-agenda-files)` i.e. call the function, you will get the list that was calculated at initialization. But if you look at the doc string of the *variable* `org-agenda-files` with `C-h v org-agenda-files`, you will see that:

```
...
If an entry is a directory, all files in that directory that are matched
by ‘org-agenda-file-regexp’ will be part of the file list.
...
```

So you can set it in your init file like this:

```el
;; either ...
(setq org-directory "~/org/")
(setq org-agenda-files (list org-directory))

;; ... or more directly without the variable
(setq org-agenda-file '("~/org/"))
```

In conjunction with the default value of `org-agenda-file-regexp` which matches files that have an `.org` suffix, this will ensure that the list of files that `org-agenda` uses will include *all* files under the indicated directory with a `.org` suffix, *including any newly created ones* (something which your current form does not do).

You might end up with a very slow agenda if you have all (or lots of) your Org mode files under that directory, particularly after a couple of years of journaling. But that's a problem for another question.